# Selenium python javascript popup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in Python to navigate to a website and fill in a form. There is a section of the code that let's you click on a button to open a pop-up node tree using javascript. I am able to click the button using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get('htto://someurl.com')
popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick and @href = "javascript:;" and img/@alt = "Node Tree"]')
popup.click()
driver.switch_to.alert
```

At this point, everything on website becomes unclickable both in the pop-up box and on the actual site. What is causing this? Unfortunately I can't share the Javascript as it's internal to my company.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.switch_to.alert`?

Comment: @alecxe I just added that line to the original post. When I try to click anything, I am still getting the black circle with the line through it (meaning I can't click anything). I'm not sure why clicking that button through Selenium is any different then manually clicking it. Also this is not a true popup in that it's not a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

rather than switch_to.alert, how about drv.switch_to_alert()
where drv is your driver instance.

I can't see anything in the python source that's immediately obvious by grepping that looks like the switch_to. syntax is supported.

I would have posted a comment, but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: No luck with this. PyCharm actually recommends the switch.